# Cannot access Google Task API 403 Forbidden Response

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to connect to Google tasks without using Google client libraries. The following code returns a 403 forbidden error. Just not sure what I'm missing. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
try {
                Bundle options = new Bundle();
                AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
                Account[] list = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
                Account acct = list[0];
                manager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", null);
                AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> acc = manager.getAuthToken(
                        acct,
                        "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks",
                        options, true, null, null);

                Bundle bundle = acc.getResult();
                String token = bundle
                        .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                Log.i("Token: ", token); // token does have value

                String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=long_winded_api_key_from_console_here";
                HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                getRequest.addHeader("client_id",
                        "clientID_from_console_here.apps.googleusercontent.com");
                getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(getRequest,
                        new BasicResponseHandler()); // exception raised here

                httpclient.execute(getRequest, new BasicResponseHandler());

                Log.i("###", responseBody); // cannot get the response here

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // exception raised here
            catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows how to get started using the Google Drive API from Android. It lets the user pick an account, gets consent from them then acquires a credentials object that can be used for API access with the Google client libraries:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

In your case you are trying to use the Tasks API, however the authentication parts should be identical:

In Step 2, enable the Tasks API instead.

Step 4 shows how to get an access token for a particular scope:

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

Change the scope to the task API scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks`

Then I would recommend using the Google client libraries for the rest like the Drive example.

If for any reason you don't want to use the client libraries, and prefer crafting the HTTP request yourself, the authorization header you want should look like the following (unable to test right now):

```
getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + credential.getToken());
```

Comment: Thanks for that @aejidenberg but the link you supplied works with the google APIs which I'm trying to avoid. I replaced my Authorization header with the line you supplied but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you follow the other steps in the Drive example (e.g. generate certificate, enable API, register Android client etc)? Can you post the new code you have? (and what is the exact message that came along with the 403?)

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @aeijdenberg. I did generate a certificate and enable the API. By register the android client I assume you mean with the SHA1 string? None of this affected my code though. Im slightly confuse about the http response though as when I enter the url into a browser, it returns a 401 error but in the log the response status line shows as HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

Comment: {
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured",
"message": "Access Not Configured"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Access Not Configured"
}
}

Comment: When you enter the URL in a browser you aren't sending any Authorization header so you will see a 401 response indicating invalid credentials.  The 403 error message you are seeing indicates that the credentials are fine, but you are not authorized to make the call.  I've seen that specific message appear when the service is not enabled in the API Console for a project.  Can you double-check that the "Tasks API" shows as enabled on the services tab for the project that contains the client ID that you created when you entered the SHA-1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly sure if this is the cause, since you seem to do the same steps
I do, but you might want to try to use **"Manage your tasks"** instead of
**"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks"**. That might be the reason for
the 403.

Here is how I connect without client libraries.
Full source available here:
[apiTalker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NotePad/blob/master/NoNonsenseNotes/src/com/nononsenseapps/notepad/sync/googleapi/GoogleAPITalker.java)

First I get the access token:

```
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "Manage your tasks";

public static String getAuthToken(AccountManager accountManager,
        Account account, String authTokenType, boolean notifyAuthFailure) {

    Log.d(TAG, "getAuthToken");
    String authToken = "";
    try {
        // Might be invalid in the cache
        authToken = accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account,
                authTokenType, notifyAuthFailure);
        accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authToken);

        authToken = accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account,
                authTokenType, notifyAuthFailure);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
    }
    catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return authToken;
}
```

Connecting and listing the available tasklists:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists";

public static String AuthUrlEnd() {
    return "key=" + Config.GTASKS_API_KEY;
}

public static String AllLists(final String pageToken) {
    String result = BASE_URL + "?";

    if (pageToken != null && !pageToken.isEmpty()) {
        result += "pageToken=" + pageToken + "&";
    }

    result += AuthUrlEnd();
    return result;
}

public String getListOfLists(ArrayList<GoogleTaskList> list)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    String eTag = "";
    String pageToken = null;
    do {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(AllLists(pageToken));
        httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + authToken);

        // Log.d(TAG, "request: " + AllLists());
        AndroidHttpClient.modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse(httpget);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(
                    parseResponse(client.execute(httpget))).nextValue();

            // Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse.toString());
            if (jsonResponse.isNull(NEXTPAGETOKEN)) {
                pageToken = null;
            }
            else {
                pageToken = jsonResponse.getString(NEXTPAGETOKEN);
            }
            // No lists
            if (jsonResponse.isNull("items")) {
                break;
            }

            eTag += jsonResponse.getString("etag");

            JSONArray lists = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            int size = lists.length();
            int i;

            // Lists will not carry etags, must fetch them individually if
            // that
            // is desired
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonList = lists.getJSONObject(i);
                //Log.d("nononsenseapps", jsonList.toString(2));
                list.add(new GoogleTaskList(jsonList, accountName));
            }
        }
        catch (PreconditionException e) {
            // // Can not happen in this case since we don't have any etag!
            // } catch (NotModifiedException e) {
            // // Can not happen in this case since we don't have any etag!
            // }
        }
    } while (pageToken != null);

    return eTag;
}
```

Here is how I parse the response:

```
public static String parseResponse(HttpResponse response)
        throws ClientProtocolException, PreconditionException {
    String page = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Response Code: "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 403) {
        // Invalid authtoken
        throw new ClientProtocolException("Status: 403, Invalid authcode");
    }

    else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 412) { //
        /*
         * Precondition failed. Object has been modified on server, can't do
         * update
         */
        throw new PreconditionException(
                "Etags don't match, can not perform update. Resolve the conflict then update without etag");
    }

    /*
     * else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 304) { throw new
     * NotModifiedException(); }
     */
    else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 400) {
        // Warning: can happen for a legitimate case
        // This happens if you try to delete the default list.
        // Resolv it by considering the delete successful. List will still
        // exist on server, but all tasks will be deleted from it.
        // A successful delete returns an empty response.
        // Make a log entry about it anyway though
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Response was 400. Either we deleted the default list in app or did something really bad");
        throw new PreconditionException(
                "Tried to delete default list, undelete it");
    }
    else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204) {
        // Successful delete of a tasklist. return empty string as that is
        // expected from delete

        Log.d(TAG, "Response was 204: Successful delete");
        return "";
    }
    else {

        try {
            if (response.getEntity() != null) {
                // Only call getContent ONCE
                InputStream content = AndroidHttpClient
                        .getUngzippedContent(response.getEntity());
                if (content != null) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    page = sb.toString();
                    //
                    // System.out.println(page);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return page;
}
```